# Looking for a replacement for Adobe reader

Tags: windows, gratis, pdf, pdf-viewer

I am looking for another PDF viewer instead of Adobe reader for Windows 10.
My requirements:

- Edit PDF files
- Merge/split PDF files
- Convert to other files
- Have a graphical user interface (GUI) and not be command line only
- Open source (optional)

I have looked a lot for a program like this but it's hard to find. I am willing to give up on merging/splitting, converting and being open source if really necessary.

Comment: @Izzy thanks for reminding me! I should have added that it is for Windows 10. And I'm just looking for a free software, not looking to buy one. Since I don't know if any free program will have *all* these features, I can let go of some.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Eran! I've added the corresponding tags to your question. Will be hard to find, unless you also let go of the editing part – but who knows. Good luck!

Comment: You can try [Sumatra PDF](http://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/free-pdf-reader.html). It's free and open source.

Comment: Because none of this functionality is unique to Windows 10, I have changed the Windows-10 tag to Windows.  If you are looking for a 'Universal' (aka Metro) app, please specify, so the tag can be updated to reflect this requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. As far as I know, to edit a PDF file like a 'Word' document you need to use paid version of PDF software like [Foxit Reader](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foxit_Reader). *MS Office 2013* also can convert PDF files to Word documents. In the free version of *Foxit Reader* you cannot edit a PDF file like a word document, but you can post comment, do typing and highlight text.
2. For split/merger use the free version of [PDFkt builder](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/). It is also available [here](https://portableapps.com/).
3. Use [PDFCreator](http://www.pdfforge.org/) to create PDF files using it as printer. This function also available in *Foxit Reader.*

Comment: It should be noted that the paid version of Foxit is necessary to avoid having a watermark added automatically upon editing the PDF.